# GAE Datastore saves an entity then doesn't update it using Java / Objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, development-environment, objectify

I have some [simple code](http://pastebin.com/KmrmAj54) that handles the upload of a profile image (it's the callback after `BlobstoreService` has done its voodoo).

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
        BlobstoreService blobSvc = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
        Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobSvc.getUploads(req);
        List<BlobKey> blobKeys = blobs.get(UserSvc.fieldProfileImg);
        String principalKey = req.getParameter(UserSvc.fieldPrincipalKey);

        boolean failure = true;
        if (null != blobKeys && blobKeys.size() > 0) {
                Optional<Principal> princi = GaeDataUtil.getByWebKey(principalKey);
                if (princi.isPresent()) {
                        log.info("Before adding BlobKey: " + princi.get());
                        princi.get().setProfileImgKey(blobKeys.get(0));
                        princi.get().setMiddleName("Saved"); // just to test if any other value will update
                        ofy().save().entity(princi.get()).now();
                        log.info("After adding BlobKey and saving: " + princi.get());
                        failure = false;
                        res.getWriter().print("SUCCESS");
                } else {
                        log.warning("Failed to find Principal with web key: " + principalKey);
                }
        }
        if (failure) {
                res.getWriter().print("FAIL");
        }

}
```

Everything works, except the re-saving of the retrieved entity.

#### Background Infomation

My own server-side code is submitting the profile image data to the `BlobstoreService` (let's not get into why that is so).  The submission/upload works, am able to see it in the admin/Datastore of the devserver, I get the `BlobKey` I want, can even retrieve the `Principal` from the `webKey`, but can't seem to save the updated entity. No exceptions either.

Initially when I tried this I wasn't retrieving the `BlobKey` and I noticed that the Datastore would show two special entities: `__BlobInfo__` and another one whose name I can't recall but it began and ended with `__` (double underscore).  After I flushed memcache, I could see only `__BlobInfo__` entities, the other one was nowhere to be seen. I deleted the `target\<appname>-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\local_db.bin` trying to reset the Datastore, but I still couldn't see any sign of the other special entity in the Datastore.

Is there a way to **reset** the Datastore and Blobstore on development server?

Environment:

- Development server
- Java 7
- Windows 7
- Objectify 5.1.7

Comment: Please keep code inlined here, not on pastebin.

Comment: Sometimes other users object if too much code is inlined... what's the yardstick for when to inline and when to use Pastebin and similar services?

Comment: Never pastebin. If your code is too much you don't have a [mcve] and should strip the code.

Comment: So `ofy().save().entity(princi.get()).now()` does not fail (The documentation of `now()` is *"If the computation produced an exception, it will be thrown here."*) but you don't see the update in the datastore viewer? You can reset your local env: at startup in the logs it says something about creating a sql file, delete that.

Comment: @zapl Exactly! No exceptions, but no updates either. I thought maybe inadvertently (magically) I was doing an async save, but even minutes later the update isn't there.

Comment: Can you show how the `Principal` class looks like?

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/EZN4ZQ3U . Sorry, don't want to show the whole code for perpetuity.

Comment: I only know the python and php sdks but is `princi` a `Key` object and is `princi.get()` retrieving the entity for the `Key`? I don't know exactly how the caching works in the java version, but to me it looks like you should store the return value of the first `Entity localEntity = princi.get()` and then set all of the properties on `localEntity`, then pass that same instance in `ofy().save().entity(localEntity).now();` (can't recall if objectify calls it's base entities an `Entity` or not)

Comment: @JoshJ `princi.get()` is the actual `Principal` entity (wrapped in an [`Optional`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) object to reduce chances of null reference exceptions). In Objectify if I retrieve an entity, update some values and re-save, the entity should get updated in the Datastore. So there isn't anything wrong with that part of the code...

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a work around for resetting the blob store and data store entries in just the dev server then you can try and change the application name in the `appengine-web.xml`

`<application>appname</application>`

If you provide a different(dummy) name here it should reset things in dev server if you re-run the dev server.